# How to point prefixed and unprefixed route to same action in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I make

```
domain.com/api/somecontroller/someaction
```

and

```
domain.com/somecontroller/someaction
```

point to the same controller action:

```
class somecontroller {

   function someaction() {

   }
}
```

Note: I don't want to re-route just one action. But I want to reroute all routes of domain.com/api/* to their corresponding URLs without the 'api' prefix.

e.g:

```
domain.com/api/controller              ->  domain.com/controller
domain.com/api/controller/action       ->  domain.com/controller/action
domain.com/api/controller/action/param ->  domain.com/controller/action/param
domain.com/api/controller/action?key=val ->  domain.com/controller/action?key=val
```

I tried adding the following in routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/api', array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index'));
Router::connect('/api/:controller', array('action'=>'index'));
Router::connect('/api/:controller/:action');
Router::connect('/api/:controller/:action.:ext');
```

It works fine for the rules defined. But I doesn't seem to cover all scenarios. Like it fails when you use URL params, or plugins and other advanced URLs.

Is there an easier way of accomplishing the task that I want?

Comment: Have you tried anything? And post your `routes.php`, please.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need those 4 rules you have as you can use wildcards (*) in CakePHP's routing system.

So in app/Config/routes.php add only one rule which will cover everything you want ..

```
Router::connect('/api/:action/*', array('controller' => 'mycontroller'));
```

Then, every request that is like http://domain.com/api/someaction, will end up at http://domain.com/mycontroller/someaction.

The only thing you need to change in my code example is the name of the controller, I have *mycontroller* specified above.

the **:action** part you see is basically a placeholder for any actions specified in the request and the ***** is a wildcard.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add both to your routes config and point them to the same place.

This should help you:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html